# Post videos to twitter

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I got success to post photos to Twitter. But how do i post videos to Twitter using my C# application?. For posting pictures i used Tweetsharp. Can we use Tweetsharp's SendTweetWithMediaOptions to share video? if yes How?

This is sample i used to share picture to twitter

```
  Bitmap img = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath(@"~/Images/Special/" + Convert.ToInt32(offerId) + "/" + specialOffer.Picture));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Dictionary<string, Stream> images = new Dictionary<string, Stream> { { "mypicture", ms } };

            var tweet = tweetservice.SendTweetWithMedia(new SendTweetWithMediaOptions { Status = urlTextToShare, Images = images });
```

and what i need is something like below image

[image]

Comment: The one who down voted this question please tell me the answer.

Comment: Your question is vague and open ended. What have you tried, in what way did it not work. Post example code.

Comment: I don't know how to do this. That is the reason why i asked this question here. If you want to refer my picture posting code please see my edited question.

Comment: Now avilable to upload videos in twitter look at the documentation  https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot upload videos to Twitter.   If you [read their documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media), it says:

> Supported image formats are PNG, JPG and GIF, including animated GIFs of up to 3MB

You choices are either to upload an animated GIF or include a URL to a video (such as YouTube / Vimeo)

Comment: Hi Terence, Thank you for your replay. But i can find some posts in Twitter like the image which i posted along with my edited question. I also want to share a youtube URL. But when i try to share one it is only showing its link to that video, but the video is not showing as my picture. But what i need is same as that picture.

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing wrong. Every valid YouTube URL will show a video (unless it is private). Do you have a link to a Tweet you've tried which doesn't work?

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to say that it is now possible to publish videos with the Twitter REST API. Tweetinvi is not yet fully supporting it but you can use the code available in following address to publish mp4 videos : http://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/discussions/640413.

Comment: now avilable to upload videos https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media